# Using Git and somehow my local files have disappeared

Tags: git

I wanted to push to Git for the first time today. I managed to get the data of my folder to my repo on Github.

The issue is: I had another folder called Archive which has disappeared from the VS code view. I checked the actual directory location inside Windows Explorer and it's not there either. It's not in the Recycling Bin (where deleted VS code files go) either. Where could this folder and its files be?

I feel like I may have tried to push the missing folder at the beginning but not sure how it got deleted. I think I did a `git reset --hard` at some point but how would this affect my local computer? And if it did, surely there would be somewhere the deleted files should be?

How can I retrieve this?

Comment: `git reset --hard` throws away all your local changes since the last commit.  So yes that is very likely the reason.

Comment: ...and no, there is no recovering these changes after a `git reset --hard` with git itself. If absolutely necessary, you'll have to turn to OS file recovery features or something alike. How did you get the idea that git commands don't affect your local computer? (or is that remark just about `git reset` ?)

Comment: perhaps you switched branches or checked out an old commit?

Answer (score 1):

If you had local files that were not committed and you run "git reset --hard" you will lose those files and everything locally will be reset back to the time of the last commit. This is why people should commit often and if possible push changes to a remote test repo, too.